# Theme Kit Error : Command could not be found

Tags: windows

One problem with Shopify

Command: $ theme config -s toy-boxxxx.myshopify.com -t 152125014311 -p
shaptka_00cb959215b54c45d4cbb361c46060cb
My problem is this command is not working, the error is (This command not be found).
Please fix this error.

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHXb8.png)